# How to rewrite Mercurial pull URL to not point to HOME

Tags: linux, installation, mercurial

I have a Linux server that will be hosting multiple mercurial repositories over SSH.
All the repositories lie in the folder HG_HOME/repos, where HG_HOME ist the home directory of the hg user.

The following command for pull works:

```
ssh://hg@my.server/repos/REPO_NAME
```

For ease of use, I would however like to use:

```
ssh://hg@my.server/REPO_NAME
```

Is this possible? If yes, where do I configure it?

The version used is 4.0

Comment: What serving method do you use? There's quite a few listed here: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories

Comment: We use hgadmin as a serving method and hgweb for web-based

Comment: What's the repopath setting in hgadmin's config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is not an exact solution, but the schemes extension (which comes with Mercurial) may be a usable alternative. It allows you to create your own URL schemes, for example:

```
[extensions]
schemes=
[schemes]
my = ssh://hg@my.server/repos/
```

This allows you to then use the `my` URL scheme, e.g.:

```
hg pull my://REPO_NAME
```

Comment: This looks very promising, thank you! Do you happen to know if there is a possiblity to configure this globally on the server without the developers having to update their local .hgrc?

Comment: This cannot be done server-side (as processing ssh URLs is done entirely by the client), but if you use a standardized Mercurial installation, it can be preconfigured in `<install-root>/etc/mercurial/hgrc` or `/etc/mercurial/hgrc`.